# Como utilizar Conditions de busca informado pelo usuário ( Não obrigatório )

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

Minha dúvida está um pouco complicada de explicar, mas vamos lá.
Eu tenho vários Checkboxs, onde não é obrigatório seleciona-los para fazer a busca, apenas são parâmetros de busca, minha dúvida, como fazer essa busca "relativa"? Os parametros são os checkboxs selecionados. Não estou sabendo como fazer isto. Se alguém puder me ajudar.
Uma imagem dos checkboxs :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pensei em fazer assim, meu JS:

```
var checkeds = new Array();
$("input[name='marcar[]']:checked").each(function (){
   checkeds.push( $(this).val());
});
var obj = $("#paramsPesquisa");
if($(obj).find("input[id='cd_seq_pedido']:checked").length > 0){
    var cd_seq_pedido = $(obj).find("input[id='cd_seq_pedido']:checked").val();
}else{
    var cd_seq_pedido = "";
}
```

Método Ajax :

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/pedidoOnline/index.php/Pedidos/checkbox_marcados",
      data: {
          'marcar':checkeds,
          'cd_seq_pedido': cd_seq_pedido,
          'cd_pedido': cd_pedido
      },
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      } 
    });
```

E então no controller, como montar essa Query "relativa" pois será apenas o que o usuário selecionar, sendo apenas possível apenas 1 resultado selecionado por checkbox.

Quero trazer estes fields, mas como colocar as conditions aqui ?

```
   $pesquisa = $this->PesquisaPedOnline->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('cd_seq_pedido', 'cd_pedido', 'ds_cpl_tamanho_interno'),
            'conditions' => array(
                    ?????
            )
    ));`
```

Comment: Cara, mas quais são exatamente os dados que você ta procurando, o que voce quer exibir com esses dados?

Answer (score 0):

Edson, uma sugestão seria fazer da seguinte forma no cake:

```php
$params = $this->request->data;
if(isset($params['pesquisa1'])){ 
    $conditions['Model.campo1'] = $params['pesquisa1']; 
}
if(isset($params['pesquisa2'])){ 
    $conditions['Model.campo2'] = $params['pesquisa2']; 
}
// assim sucessivamente com todos os campos

// depois joga isso no FIND
$pesquisa = $this->PesquisaPedOnline->find('all',
    array(
        'fields' => array('cd_seq_pedido', 'cd_pedido', 'ds_cpl_tamanho_interno'),
        'conditions' => $conditions // assim
    )
);
```

Faço dessa forma sempre que tenho vários parametros e eles não são obrigatórios.

Answer (score 0):

#### SQL

```
CREATE TABLE tb_teste(
    cd_pedido INTEGER,
    cd_seq_pedido INTEGER,
    cd_marca INTEGER,
    cd_tipo INTEGER
);
```

Promeiramente defina seus `inputs` com o nome da coluna na tabela

#### HTML

```
<form id="form_pesquisa" method="post">
<?php
    $marcas = array(
        1 => 'TESTE 1',
        2 => 'TESTE 2',
        3 => 'TESTE 3',
        4 => 'TESTE 4',
        5 => 'TESTE 5',
        6 => 'TESTE 6',
    );
    foreach($marcas as $cdMarca => $dsMarca){
        echo sprintf('<p><input name="cd_marca[]" value="%s" type="checkbox"/><label>%s</label></p>', $cdMarca, $dsMarca);
    }
?>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

#### PHP

```
$post = $_POST;

$conditions = array();
if(isset($post['cd_marca'])){
    $conditions[] = sprintf('Model.cd_marca IN (%s)', implode(',', $post['cd_marca']));
}

# REALIZA A PESQUISA EM BANCO
$pesquisa = $this->PesquisaPedOnline->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('cd_seq_pedido', 'cd_pedido', 'ds_cpl_tamanho_interno'),
    'conditions' => $conditions,
));
```

O problema desta metodo é que teria de fazer um `isset` para cada coluna filtrada,
agora se você quiser deixar isso mais dinamico ainda pode realizar atraves de um duplo
foreach, contudo vai ser necessario implementar mais um `indice` nos `inputs`

#### HTML

```
<form id="form_pesquisa" method="post">
<?php
    $dadosPesquisa = array(
        'cd_marca' => array(
            1 => 'TESTE 1',
            2 => 'TESTE 2',
            3 => 'TESTE 3',
            4 => 'TESTE 4',
            5 => 'TESTE 5',
            6 => 'TESTE 6',
        ),
        'cd_tipo' => array(
            1 => 'TESTE 1',
            2 => 'TESTE 2',
            3 => 'TESTE 3',
            4 => 'TESTE 4',
            5 => 'TESTE 5',
            6 => 'TESTE 6',
        )
    );  

    foreach($dadosPesquisa as $campo => $dados){
        foreach($dados as $cd => $ds){
            echo sprintf('<p><input name="pesquisa[%s][]" value="%s" type="checkbox"/><label>%s</label></p>', $campo, $cd, $ds);
        }
    }
?>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

#### PHP

```
$post = $_POST;

$conditions = array();
if(isset($post['pesquisa'])){
    foreach($post['pesquisa'] as $campo => $dados){
        $conditions[] = sprintf('Model.%s IN (%s)', $campo, implode(',', $dados));
    }
}
```